# attributeBindings not working with containerViews

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I am trying to use twitter bootstrap button groups of check-box type in ember frame work. I have a container view to hold the buttons. Each buttons are child of this container View. In order to the check box functionality of this buttons work properly, i have to add an attribute called 'Data-Toggle'. But the attributeBindings is not working with ContainerViews. It is working fine with normal Views and CollectionViews. Is this a Bug or problem in Application code? is there any way to overcome this? like by using template and loading whole HTML using that??? Please help me ASAP

Here is my code

```
$(function(){
Ed.View.Header = Em.ContainerView.extend({
classNames: ['btn-group'],
tagName:'div',
attributeBindings: ['data-toggle'],
data-toggle: 'buttons-checkbox',
childViews: ['archived', 'created', 'started', 'completed'],

'archived':Em.View.extend({
  classNames: ['btn'],
  tagName:'button',

  title:'Hide Archived',
  valueBinding: "Ed.state.hideArchived"
}),

'created':Em.View.extend({
classNames: ['btn'],
tagName:'button',
  title:'Hide Created',
  valueBinding: "Ed.state.hideCreated"
}),

'started':Em.View.extend({
classNames: ['btn'],
tagName:'button',
  title:'Hide Started',
  valueBinding: "Ed.state.hideStarted"
}),

'completed':Em.View.extend({
classNames: ['btn'],
tagName:'button',
  title:'Hide Completed',
  valueBinding: "Ed.state.hideCompleted"
})
});
});
```

Comment: I just understood that the problem is the hyphen in the name of the attribute. it renders the attribute without hyphen. any body can help me to render this attribute?

Answer (score 3):

There is not enough code to run your sample, but just try it:

```
attributeBindings: ['dataToggle:data-toggle'],
dataToggle: 'buttons-checkbox',
```

It should make the job.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help Bro. as the hyphen was the problem , i found the fix like this

```
 attributeBindings: ["data-toggle"],
'data-toggle': 'buttons-checkbox',
```

this rendered as

```
<div id="ember346" class="ember-view btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
<button id="ember354" class="ember-view btn"></button>
<button id="ember365" class="ember-view btn"></button>
<button id="ember376" class="ember-view btn"></button>
<button id="ember387" class="ember-view btn"></button></div>
```